# Can I publish a non-commercial game that uses assets from a 30 years old Konami game on Steam, Google Play and App Store?

Tags: assets, legal, copyright

Do major platforms like Google Play, App Store, and Steam allow apps to use assets without owner permission in case of 100% non-commercial releases? Do companies like Konami care?

Comment: The platforms might allow it, not because of it being legal (it isn't), but because sometimes they aren't very good at checking. You get in trouble later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not legally, no, you cannot use it.

"Abandonware" is not a legal concept, and the original copyright ownership still stands, even if the original product is no longer being sold. Likewise it doesn't matter if you're offering your's for free, you would still be using material that is legally owned by someone else.

Finally, and as always, if you want a qualified legal opinion, then consult a qualified legal professional. The opinions of random anonymous people on the internet will not hold up in court.

Comment: It is obvious about the original copyright. I was curious if there's an exception for non-commercial uses. Thank you.

Comment: @mzg No, there isn't. Copyright laws don't care if you make money. Best case scenario: Konami sends a DMCA notice and your game is kicked off the stores. Worst case scenario: They sue you for everything you have and force you into a settlement because you can't afford a lawyer to defend yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @Philipp